# How to return a function with variable different than variable used in Module

Tags: function-construction

I have a module function where I am calculating an interpolated polynomial using Newton's method. The end of this module is what is actually forming the function. Currently, in the module, I have the last line having a function which is what I want returned from the module function. Instead, I am getting x$ as the variable. Here is the code:

```
NewtonInterpolation[xList_, yList_] := 
 Module[{n, aList, NewtonInterPoly, x},
  n = Length[xList];
  aList = Table["", n];
  aList[[1]] = yList[[1]];
  Do[aList[[k]] = (yList[[k]] - 
       Sum[aList[[i]]*
         Product[xList[[k]] - xList[[j]], {j, 1, i - 1}], {i, 1, 
         k - 1}])/(Product[
       xList[[k]] - xList[[j]], {j, 1, k - 1}]), {k, 2, n}];
  NewtonInterPoly[x_] = 
   Sum[aList[[i]]*Product[x - xList[[j]], {j, 1, i - 1}], {i, 1, n}]]
xList = {1, 2, 3};
yList = {1, 4, 9};
Poly[y] = NewtonInterpolation[xList, yList];
Print[Expand[Poly[y]]]
```

which returns x$^2, but I want it to return y^2. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I ran your code and got a bunch of errors. Can you check to see if you have a typo or have included all the correct information? EDIT: Nevermind, I know what the issue is. Pre-V10.1, `Table["", n]` needs to be `Table["", {n}]`.

Comment: If you remove `x` from your list of local `Module` variables, it will work, but then you will *always* need to use `x`. Perhaps you should redefine things this way: `NewtonInterpolation[xList_, yList_, x_] := ...` and remove `x` from your list of `Module` variables. Then run `Poly[y_] = NewtonInterpolation[xList, yList, y]`. Also, you don't need `NewtonInterPoly[x_] = ` in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few small mistakes in the code you posted:

1) The table iterator should be in brackets.

```
 aList = Table["", n];
```

Should be

```
 aList = Table["", {n}];
```

2) I'm not sure what this line was intended to do:

```
  NewtonInterPoly[x_] =
```

but the way you are using it, it does nothing; you are using the result returned by the assignment, which is just the value from right hand side.

To answer your question:
`x` should not be declared by the module, it should be passed in. There are two ways you could do this: add to the pattern, like so:

```
NewtonInterpolation[xList_, yList_, x_] :=
```

or (I would prefer):

```
NewtonInterpolation[xList_, yList_][x_] :=
```

The other option is to have NewtonInterpolation create a function, like so:

```
NewtonInterpolation[xList_, yList_] := 
  Function[{x}, 
    Module[ ...
```

And, if you change the pattern defining NewtonInterpolation, you should be sure to call

```
  ClearAll[NewtonInterpolation]
```

Comment: note the `Table` syntax is correct with newer versions.

Comment: In my experience table with brackets is always more robust (`Do` also got a similar quality-of-life update, but it seems to give errors as well). I would agree with recommendation 1, even though it isn't supposed to matter.

Answer (score 2):

one approach is to have your module return a pure function. Replace the last line with :

```
Evaluate[Sum[
   aList[[i]]*Product[# - xList[[j]], {j, 1, i - 1}], {i, 1, n}]] &
```

aside, for this example you might want to do :

```
Simplify@Evaluate ...
```

(Then you wont need to `Expand` the result )

the usage is:

```
Poly[y_] = NewtonInterpolation[xList, yList]@y;
```

or simply:

```
Poly=NewtonInterpolation[xList, yList]
```

(Note starting your own symbols with caps is not  good practice)